# Why does the argument to string.search behave like a Regex?

Tags: javascript, string, search

I don't know about other Javascript engines, but in V8, including Chrome and [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), `String.prototype.search` behaves in an unexpected fashion.

```
> "054".search("0.4")
0 // expected -1
> "Sample String 007".search("0.7")
14 // expected -1
> "Sample String 0.7".search("0.7")
14 // expected behavior
```

If this is the expected behavior, why is that the case?  And if this is the expected behavior, how do I properly search for a String without regular expressions coming in to play?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MDN's page on [String.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search#Parameters) has this to say about the function's argument:

> If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using `new RegExp(obj)`.

Therefore, the strings in your examples are correctly coerced into a regular expression objects.  Your tests are equivalent to:

```
"054".search(new RegExp("0.4"))
"Sample String 007".search(new RegExp("0.7"))
"Sample String 0.7".search(new RegExp("0.7"))
```

and they return the correct result.

As @meetamit notes for your second question, you actually want `indexOf`, which expects a string argument, not a regular expression.

Comment: Right. And to search without RegExp, just use the indexOf method. `"some string".indexOf("whatever");`

Comment: Exactly what I was wondering.  The common problem of knowing too many languages and not remembering which function exactly applies.  Thanks!